# Get structured stack information in GoLang

Tags: go

I'm looking at using `runtime.Stack` to parse information on goroutines (looking for leaks). The issue is that `runtime.Stack` returns its output as a string that has to be parsed, and it requires a byte buffer input of sufficient size. I know there are some libraries like [gostackparse](https://github.com/DataDog/gostackparse) and [panicparse](https://github.com/maruel/panicparse), but neither of them work for `GODEBUG=tracebackancestors=<n>` (where n > 0). I need this because I want to verify leaks for goroutines which are descendents of the current stack frame.

Is there a way to get the structured output of `runtime.Stack` that works with `tracebackancestors`?

Comment: Delve can print a stacktrace of ancestors of the selected goroutine 
https://github.com/go-delve/delve/tree/master/Documentation/cli#stack.
Can that help?